# How to validate extra key in the Json Schema in C# and throw error

Tags: c#, json

So I have two Json files where I am validating them and If one file has extra key, I would like to throw an error. Right now with my below code, it does not give me any error, it takes the extra key with it, though I get an error if a key is missing but not if I have an extra key.

My piece of code is as follows:

```
async Task<JsonSchema> GetDataSchemaAsync( string format )
    {
        if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( format ) )
            throw new ArgumentException( "Table data format is invalid" );

        var schemaUri = new Uri( _schemaBaseUri, $"{format}.json");
        using var client = new WebClient();
        var json = client.DownloadString( schemaUri );

        return await JsonSchema.FromJsonAsync( json );
    }

  var schema = await GetDataSchemaAsync( format ); 
  var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(line);
  var errors = validator.Validate(data, schema);
```

My format file has the schema with keys mentioned and my line is my json format with values and an extra key.

Please advise.

Comment: would be helpful if you can show me or refer me to right documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema supports the `additionalProperties: boolean` setting. The default value for this setting is `true` so additional properties will be allowed during validation. [Docs](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html)

Set

```
"additionalProperties": false
```

in your schema and the validator will throw an error if the dataobject has any properties not defined in the schema.